# How can I find "holes" in mp3 files?

Tags: audio, mp3

I have several mp3 files in which I found out that they have "holes" of silence.
Is there a way to scan a directory of files to find those files.
I wouldn't want to move one by one to check them.
A programmatic solution is also welcomed.

Thanks!

Comment: For normal editing, try Audacity. It's easy to use.

Comment: Yes, but it is a manual solution. I'd like to have a directory scanner